# How to perform IISRESET with Powershell Script

Tags: iis, powershell

Does anyone know how to perform IISRESET with a PowerShell script? I'm using the PowerGUI editor with PowerShell 1.0 installed on a Windows 2008 box.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 44):

You can do it with the Invoke-Command cmdlet:

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset}
```

**UPDATE**:

You can also simplify the command using the & call operator:

`& {iisreset}`

Answer (score 12):

Having used `& {iisreset}` with occasional failure lead me to this:

`Start-Process "iisreset.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait`

Now it waits for `iisreset.exe` to end gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

This works well for me.  In this application, I don't care about the return code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe -ArgumentList /RESTART -RedirectStandardOutput .\iisreset.txt
Get-Content .\iisreset.txt | Write-Log -Level Info
```

The Write-Log cmdlet is a custom one I use for logging, but you could substitute something else.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is very old, but you can run any command line processes from Powershell's command line. So you would just need a script that calls IISReset with whatever switches you need.

Answer (score 2):

`iisreset.exe` supports computer names as a parameter. An example below shows basic idea how to reset IIS on multiple servers:

```
$servers = @()
$servers += 'server1'
$servers += 'server2'
...
$servers += 'serverN'
```

Since `iisreset.exe` doesn't support multivalued parameters we have to wrap it in a loop:

```
$servers | %{ iisreset $_ /restart /noforce }
```

You may want to add simple monitoring:

```
$servers | %{ Write-Host "`n`n$_`n" -NoNewline ; iisreset $_ /restart /noforce /timeout:30 }
```

If you have many servers you may be interested in failures only:

```
$servers | %{ Write-Host "`n`n$_`n" -NoNewline ; iisreset $_ /restart /noforce /timeout:30 | Select-String "failed" }
```

Multiline version for better readability:

```
foreach ( $server in $servers ) {
    Write-Host "`n`n$server`n" -NoNewline ; 
    iisreset $server /restart /noforce /timeout:30 | Select-String "failed"
}
```

I would strongly recommend testing your script with `/status` before implementing `/reset` action:

```
$servers | %{ iisreset $_ /status }
```

You may check stopped components with `/status` as well:

```
$servers | %{ Write-Host "`n`n$_`n" -NoNewline ; iisreset $_ /status | Select-String "Stopped" }
```

**Reference**

- `/restart` is the default parameter. `iisreset.exe` is using `/restart` in case no other actions params specified
- `/noforce` will prevent `iisreset.exe` from running in case of an error.
- `/timeout` - sometime you need to allow server more time to process request to avoid IIS stuck in *Stopped* state.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but create a script with a body of "iisreset /noforce"

Here's an example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785436.aspx

Answer (score 1):

### IIS Stop or Start (tested)

```
WaitForExit and ExitCode work fine
```

---

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Diagnostics").FullName
$procinfo = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$procinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$procinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$procinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$procinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$procinfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe"
$procinfo.Arguments = "/stop"
$proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.StartInfo = $procinfo
[void]$proc.Start()
$proc.WaitForExit()
$exited = $proc.ExitCode
$proc.Dispose()

    Write-Host $exited
```

Answer (score -3):

I found using the simple command below the easiest.

D:\PS\psexec \server_name iisreset